# How do I find the closest rounded values according to a specific set of criteria

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I am not well versed at math and deal with a particular problem drawing graphs on html5 canvas.

Given that I have:

- a price range between min and max price that I need to put on a Y axis
- A specific number of 'buckets' in which to divide this price range.

For example, I could have historical Bitcoin prices:

- Min price of 2939,7
- Max price of 4380
- 9 buckets to fill

These prices however can be entirely different, so there is a certain order of magnitude:

- round by 500
- round by 100
- round by 50
- round by 25
- round by 10
- round by 5
- round by 2.5 or 2
- round by 1
- round by 0.5
- round by 0.25 or 0.20
- round by 0.10

If I were to zoom in on the map, the number of buckets wouldn't change, but the price levels would change.

A good example of what I want to achieve is something like TradingView: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/SsrQxrf0/

[image]

But zoomed out: 
[image]

They have some way to even stretch these buckets dynamically.
I've been thinking about this, but it is really giving me brain tumor...
What is the right approach to start on this?

I try to keep my basic strategy simple:

- Determine the number of pixels to use per bucket and calculate nr of buckets based on the canvas size;
- Find the total price range to be displayed and find out the price per bucket by simple division: price difference between min and max / nr of buckets;
- Now how to display these prices in nicely rounded buckets?

In my example I would have a price range of about 113.7 per bucket.
But I've got no idea how to use this information to get to the desired result, and that is to nicely round these buckets.

Any advice on strategies are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a simple function currently, probably there are better ways to fix this, but this should do for now.

```
const buckets = [1, 2, 2.5, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 250, 500, 1000];

const findPriceIntervalPerGridSquare = ({ minPrice, maxPrice, nrSquares }) => {
  const priceRange = maxPrice - minPrice;

  let idealBucket;
  for(let bucket of buckets) {
    if ((priceRange / nrSquares) < bucket) {
      idealBucket = bucket;
      break;
    }
  }

  return idealBucket;
};
```

If you have something better, do let me know.